# Django get all objects whose many to many filed contains a filter

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have 3 models:

- City: indicating a city
- Titles: indicating job titles
- Contacts: indicating people. A person can have multiple titles and multiple cities

Now, given an city object and a title object, I want to query for all people that have those objects in their instance. Basically something like "All Lawyers in NY".

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Title(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name_surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    title = models.ManyToManyField(Title)
    city = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

Comment: The problem with this modeling is that you do not know what title belongs to what city. We simply have a collection of titles, and a collection of cities. So the titles can be software engineer and barman, and the cities NY en LA, but we do not know what title that person has in NY and what title in LA.

Comment: For the time being, if you have a title you have that title across all the cities you have

Comment: hey @WillemVanOnsem, I made another question on django models here and it seems like you really know this so any suggestion would be super appreciated! 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477287/django-restrict-value-to-a-foreign-key-of-a-foreign-key?noredirect=1#comment121020637_68477287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Contract.objects.filter(
    title__title_name='Lawyer',
    city__name='NY'
)
```

**But**, the modeling does not make much sense, since here a `Contract` relates to multiple `Title`s and multiple `City`s, but it is unclear what title belongs to what city.

Imagine that we have a person who is a software engineer in New York, and a barman in Los Angeles, then the modelling can not make a distinction between this person, and a person who is a barman in New York, and a software engineer in Los Angeles.

We can model this with a `Person` and a `Contract` that refers to a city and a title, so:

```
class City(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state=models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Title(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=Falsee)
    name_surname = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then we can determine such person with:

```
Person.objects.filter(
    contract__title__title_name='Lawyer',
    contract__city__name='NY'
)
```

Then we thus retrieve all `Person`s that have at least a `Contract` with lawyer as `title_name`, and NY as `name` for the `city`.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need to distinguish between cities and titles for my specific case but either way the query makes sense!!! Thanks!